# "Correct" way to manage DNS on remote machine with .NET app

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, iis, asp.net

We have a web server that runs a WCMS which allows users to add their domains to it. The DNS server is a separate machine. We are using Windows on all applicable machines.

How should the DNS records be managed remotely? We need to be able to add or remove domains from the DNS server. When adding, default records will be created, such as MX, a few A records and so forth. When removing a domain, the domain itself and all of its records would simply be pitched.

Answer (score 1):

The [DNS WMI Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms682125.aspx) is your best bet.